# Why can't I see in console.log() the server code of socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am starting to learn how to use socket.io and I've been trying to figure this out for the last couple of days but I don't get 2 things.

1. Why, after starting the server and loading my respective url (localhost:8088) does it take so long for my alert to show up?
2. Why can't I see the server code of socket.io? for example in the next chunk of code I never see in console my data from "my other event".

server (app.js):

```
var app = require('express')()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8088);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) { 

  socket.emit('news', { 
    hello: 'world' 
  });

  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });

});
```

client (index.html):

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect();

  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    alert(data.hello);

    socket.emit('my other event', { 
        my: 'data' 
    });

  });

</script>
```

Comment: Which version of express are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It might be the incompability between express 3.0 and socket.io

Try this:

```
var express = require('express'),;
var http = require('http');
var app = express();

var server = module.exports = http.createServer(app);
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

server.listen(8088);
```